# App crash in OnBackStackChange listener (cant get fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using an `Activity` which loads `Fragment List` and `Fragment Detail`. `Fragment D` changes the toolbar title application-wise when its opened. When the user leaves `Fragment D`, going back to `Fragment L` I want to reset the `toolbar` to its original title.

Here is the code I put in `mainActivity` to check if `Fragment D` gets closed.

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            Log.d("backstackbug", "back stack count = " + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
            if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0) {
            } else {
                ((ListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("LIST_F_TAG")).resetToolbar();

            }
        }
    });
```

The stack trace says I cant invoke `ListFragment.resetToolbar()` on a null object reference. (I'm on mobile gonna post the whole trace later).
I don't get how is it possible that the `ListFragment` is null if It is in the back stack.

The transaction:

```
private void launchListFragment(int scope){

    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack ("detail", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    Fragment newDetail = ListFragment.newInstance(scope);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, newDetail, "LIST_F_TAG")
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: please confirm while fragment transaction you have used getSupportFragmentManager() or getFragmentManager()

Comment: I have used getSupportFragmentManager. I added more code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you inverted the if block. Try this

```
@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    Log.d("backstackbug", "back stack count = " + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        ListFragment listFragment = (ListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("LIST_F_TAG");
        if (listFragment != null) {
            listFragment.resetToolbar();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to fix it. thanks, I probably messed up when I copied the code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is you are not adding the fragment to backstack

```
 fragmentTransection.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
```

Perform this step before commit